# Parse time format yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'+'

Tags: java, date, java-time

I am working with `jira` api and in one of request I get the response with date field in format like this: `2022-10-26T09:34:00.000+0000`. I need to convert this to `LocalDate` but I do not know how to to this with this strange format.
Here are some of formats I already tried:

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS")
DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME
```

but both cannot deserialize this `+` sign at the end of the date.

`Text '2022-10-27T09:34:00.000+0000' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 24`

Comment: Use `ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`, parse to an `OffsetDateTime` and convert to a `LocalDate`.

Comment: @M.Deinum `ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` doesn't work because there is no `:` in the offset.

Comment: "this strange format" is not that "strange" actually the format is even regulated in an international standard: [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: In which time zone do you want the date? Your string is in UTC, but that’s hardly the time zone in which you live? It is never the same date in all time zones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the timezone:

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
```

Checkout the documentation
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Answer (score 2):

The error message is telling you that your `DateTimeFormatter` is not able to parse the zone offset of `+0000` at the end of your `String`. That's because a `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME` just does not expect an offset, it is supposed to only parse

- year
- month of year
- day of month
- hour of day
- minute of hour
- second of minute
- fraction of second (and nanos)

That's it! **No offset! No zone!**.

But that also means it could perfectly parse everything until this offset in your example!

However, the `String` is *nearly* formatted as an `OffsetDateTime`, but unfortunately its ISO formatter expects an offset where hours and minutes are separated by a colon, e.g. `+00:00`, and your `String` does not have one.

`java.time` grants you the possibility of building a custom formatter based on an exisiting one. That's why I mentioned above that everything apart from the offset could be parsed with a `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME`. You can take that one and attach an offset-x pattern which then parses your unseparated offset. Let's call it *extending* an existing formatter, here's an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // your example String
    String someTimes = "2022-10-26T09:34:00.000+0000";
    // build a suitable formatter by extending an ISO-formatter
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                    .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
                                    .appendPattern("xxxx")
                                    .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
    // then parse
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(someTimes, dtf);
    // and print
    System.out.println(localDate);
}
```

Output:

```
2022-10-26
```

It is always a good idea to create a formatter with a `Locale`, but in most cases where exclusively numerical values are to be parsed, a formatter without a `Locale` might be sufficient. That counts for `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(String, Locale)` as well.